# Liquibase generated diffChangeLog creates constraint before creating column used in the constraint

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to `update` an existing DB with changes created by `diffChangeLog`.

I have added a column to a table, and created a unique constraint using an exsiting column and the new column.

The update fails because the changeLog generated by Liquibase creates the constraint before adding the column.

Is there any way around this besides manually changing the generated changeLog?

Comment: Are you saying that the diffChangeLog process creates the constraint on the existing and new column?  I thought you added the new column as an add to the changes generated by diffChangeLog.

Comment: Yea, I've noticed this issue as well.  I have a feeling this is a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the issue.  I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1792) with Liquibase's github page.  Not sure if or when it'll be addressed, but if anyone wants to track the issue, I provided the link.